# Laravel eager loading with limit

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group, eager-loading

I have two tables, say "users" and "users_actions", where "users_actions" has an hasMany relation with users:

**users**

```
id | name | surname | email...
```

**actions**

```
id | id_action | id_user | log | created_at
```

Model Users.php

```
class Users {
    public function action()
    { 
       return $this->hasMany('Action', 'user_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
}
```

Now, I want to retrieve a **list** of all **users** with **their LAST action**.

I saw that doing  `Users::with('action')->get();`
can easily give me the last action by simply fetching only the first result of the relation:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
   echo $user->action[0]->description;
}
```

but I wanted to avoid this of course, and just pick ONLY THE LAST action for EACH user.

I tried using a constraint, like

```
Users::with(['action' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
          ->limit(1);
    }])
->get();
```

but that gives me an incorrect result since Laravel executes this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users_actions WHERE user_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
ORDER BY created_at
LIMIT 1
```

which is of course wrong. Is there any possibility to get this without executing a query for each record using Eloquent?
Am I making some obvious mistake I'm not seeing? I'm quite new to using Eloquent and sometimes relationship troubles me.

**Edit:**

A part from the representational purpose, I also need this feature for **searching inside a relation**, say for example I want to search users where LAST ACTION = 'something'

I tried using

```
$actions->whereHas('action', function($query) {
    $query->where('id_action', 1);
});
```

but this gives me ALL the users which had had an action = 1, and since it's a log everyone passed that step.

### Edit 2:

Thanks to @berkayk looks like I solved the first part of my problem, but still I can't search within the relation.

```
Actions::whereHas('latestAction', function($query) {
    $query->where('id_action', 1);
});
```

still doesn't perform the right query, it generates something like:

```
select * from `users` where 
 (select count(*) 
   from `users_action` 
   where `users_action`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
   and `id_action` in ('1')
  ) >= 1 
order by `created_at` desc
```

I need to get the record where the ***latest*** action is 1

Comment: OMG! **too many edits**, for clean question and answer refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53837614/8740349

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My solution linked by @berbayk is cool if you want to easily get latest `hasMany` related model.

However, it couldn't solve the other part of what you're asking for, since querying this relation with `where` clause would result in pretty much the same what you already experienced - all rows would be returned, only `latest` wouldn't be latest in fact (but latest matching the where constraint).

So here you go:

*the easy way* - **get all and filter collection**:

```php
User::has('actions')->with('latestAction')->get()->filter(function ($user) {
   return $user->latestAction->id_action == 1;
});
```

---

*or the hard way* - **do it in sql** (assuming MySQL):

```php
User::whereHas('actions', function ($q) { 

  // where id = (..subquery..)
  $q->where('id', function ($q) { 

    $q->from('actions as sub')
      ->selectRaw('max(id)')
      ->whereRaw('actions.user_id = sub.user_id');

  })->where('id_action', 1);

})->with('latestAction')->get();
```

Choose one of these solutions by comparing performance - the first will **return all rows and filter possibly big collection**.

The latter will run **subquery (`whereHas`) with nested subquery (`where('id', function () {..}`)**, so both ways might be potentially slow on big table.

Comment: Wonderful! I ended up using your second suggestion, since I'm paginating the results and the first - apart from being potentially too big - won't work properly when paginating. I tweaked a bit the query to match my current implementation (have to use an IN() clause), but you put me on the right path. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Gotta wait 2 more hours before awarding the bounty, brb

Answer (score 17):

I think the solution you are asking for is explained here http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/

Define this relation in User model,

```
public function latestAction()
{
  return $this->hasOne('Action')->latest();
}
```

And get the results with

```
User::with('latestAction')->get();
```

Comment: Awesome! +1 that solves just part of my problem though, how can I search inside this relation? Say, now I have the latest, how do I verify a latest record condition? (see "edit." part in my question)

Comment: Try this `Users::with(['latestAction' => function ($query) {
$query->where('id_action', 1);
}])`

Answer (score 17):

I created a package for this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Use the `HasEagerLimit` trait in both the parent and the related model.

```php
class User extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}

class Action extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}
```

Then simply chain `->limit(1)` call in your eager-load query (which seems you already do), and you will get the latest action per user.

Comment: This was perfect, thank you! Surprising that this isn't functionality that comes out of the box.

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let change a bit the @berkayk's code.

Define this relation in `Users` model,

```
public function latestAction()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Action')->latest();
}
```

And

```
Users::with(['latestAction' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('id_action', 1);
}])->get();
```

Comment: But this hardcodes the value inside the relationship, which cannot be feasable

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand that the value should not be hardcoded. I have changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To load latest related data for each user you could get it using self join approach on actions table something like

```
select u.*, a.*
from users u
join actions a on u.id = a.user_id
left join actions a1 on a.user_id = a1.user_id
and a.created_at < a1.created_at
where a1.user_id is null
a.id_action = 1 // id_action filter on related latest record
```

To do it via query builder way you can write it as

```
DB::table('users as u')
  ->select('u.*', 'a.*')
  ->join('actions as a', 'u.id', '=', 'a.user_id')
  ->leftJoin('actions as a1', function ($join) {
        $join->on('a.user_id', '=', 'a1.user_id')
             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('a.created_at < a1.created_at'));
   })
  ->whereNull('a1.user_id')
  ->where('aid_action', 1) // id_action filter on related latest record
  ->get();
```

To eager to the latest relation for a user you can define it as a `hasOne` relation on your model like

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class User extends Model
{
    public function latest_action()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Action::class, 'user_id')
            ->leftJoin('actions as a1', function ($join) {
                $join->on('actions.user_id', '=', 'a1.user_id')
                    ->whereRaw(DB::raw('actions.created_at < a1.created_at'));
            })->whereNull('a1.user_id')
            ->select('actions.*');
    }
}
```

There is no need for dependent sub query just apply regular filter inside whereHas

```
User::with('latest_action')
    ->whereHas('latest_action', function ($query) { 
      $query->where('id_action', 1);
    })
    ->get();
```

- [Migrating Raw SQL to Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831311/migrating-raw-sql-to-eloquent/50831563?noredirect=1#comment88779538_50831563)
- [Laravel Eloquent select all rows with max created_at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959102/laravel-eloquent-select-all-rows-with-max-created-at/47959128#47959128)
- [Laravel - Get the last entry of each UID type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217420/laravel-get-the-last-entry-of-each-uid-type/49217481#49217481)
- [Laravel Eloquent group by most recent record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830138/laravel-eloquent-group-by-most-recent-record/47830291#47830291)

Answer (score -3):

Laravel Uses take() function  not Limit

Try the below Code i hope it's working fine for u

```
Users::with(['action' => function ($query) {
      $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(1);
}])->get();
```

or simply add a take method to your relationship like below

```
 return $this->hasMany('Action', 'user_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(1);
```

Comment: That's the same, take() is just another syntactic sugar, the generated query won't change

Comment: as per laravel documentation limit or take doesn't work on eager load