# Laravel 5.1 use limit in with() method of eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, limit, laravel-5.1

## Eloquent

```
$staffGroup = StaffGroup::where('id', $id)
            ->with('staffGroupRight')
            ->first();
```

In `StaffGroup` `Model`:

```
public function staffGroupRight() {
    return $this->hasMany('Modules\Staff\Http\Models\StaffGroupRight');
}
```

## what i have does is,

```
public function staffGroupRight() {
    return $this->hasMany('Modules\Staff\Http\Models\StaffGroupRight')->take(5);
}
```

but it gives total 5 rows for all `staff_group` but i want it to `limit` for one `staff_group`

## For example

There are 10 `staff_group` then it gives 5 records of `staffgrouprights` for that 10 `staff_group` but i want it 5 for single `staff_group`

here with `staffGroupRight` return `data` appropriate to `id` of `staff group`.

but i want to set `limit` in that `with()` method data.

is it possible to set `limit` in `with()` method or not...??

Comment: why dont u try paginate ?

Comment: @ujwaldhakal paginate will not does the trick for me

Comment: why ? Paginate should work

Comment: it will work but if it was in outer actually it is as a subquery so pagination will not work for me...Thank you for response. @ujwaldhakal

Comment: I created a package for this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 eager loading with limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607088/laravel-5-eager-loading-with-limit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$staffGroup = StaffGroup::where('id', $id)
        ->with(['staffGroupRight' => function($query){
            return $query->take(10);
            }])
        ->first();
```

I assume you want to take 10 record of staffGroupRight.

Comment: Thank you but it take(10) as all over but i want it as per staffgroupright...what i mean is there is multiple staffgroup and then for total staffgroup it return 10 but i want it as per staffgroup it means for each staffgroup i want 10 staffgroupright

Comment: I tested it out, it seems like no easy way to do this. except for looping each staffgroup like `foreach($staffGroup as $s){ $s->load(['staffGroupRight' => function($q){ return $q->take(5);]}); }`

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara why was this answer marked accepted? It clearly did not answer your question, as you explained in your comment.