# Eloquent get only latest per value on column

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table that stores filenames for some files, but each file can be part of a "group", is there a way to make a distinct select so that i get the latest updated record from each of the groups? taking into consideration that even on the same groups the filename is different.

EXAMPLE

```
filename     group      updated_at
asdwe.pdf    1          2020-08-21 19:38:08
123we.pdf    2          2020-08-21 17:38:08
a34we.pdf    2          2020-08-21 19:38:08
34243.pdf    3          2020-08-21 19:38:08
```

desired result

```
asdwe.pdf    1          2020-08-21 19:38:08
123we.pdf    2          2020-08-21 17:38:08
34243.pdf    3          2020-08-21 19:38:08
```

Comment: Post your query code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Get the last entry of each UID type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217420/laravel-get-the-last-entry-of-each-uid-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you desired output. We first group files by their group, then we get only the latest records by the `updated_at` column:

```
$files = Model::groupBy('group')->latest('updated_at')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use **distinct** as like :.

```
$q = Model::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
        ->distinct('group')
        ->get();
```