# How to Get Newest Data with `created_at` Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, greatest-n-per-group

How can I query the data where `id_konsul = 4`, and how can I get the latest `staflow` from `created_at` if it is the same?

example

```
id  id_konsul   staflow created_at

1   4   1   21/05/2018 11.03
2   4   2   22/05/2018 11.03
3   4   3   23/05/2018 11.03
4   4   4   24/05/2018 11.03
5   4   5   25/05/2018 11.03
6   4   6   26/05/2018 11.03
7   4   7   27/05/2018 11.03
8   4   6   28/05/2018 11.03
9   4   7   29/05/2018 11.03
10  4   7   30/05/2018 11.03
11  4   8   31/05/2018 11.03
```

than i get this

```
id  id_konsul   staflow created_at
1   4   1   21/05/2018 11.03
2   4   2   22/05/2018 11.03
3   4   3   23/05/2018 11.03
4   4   4   24/05/2018 11.03
5   4   5   25/05/2018 11.03
8   4   6   28/05/2018 11.03
10  4   7   30/05/2018 11.03
11  4   8   31/05/2018 11.03
```

Comment: Please put your code here.

Comment: use ORDER BY of mysql

Comment: use " ORDER BY `created_at`, `id` DESC  "

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get latest row per staflow attribute you can use a self join

```
select a.*
from demo a
join (
    select id_konsul,staflow, max(created_at) created_at
    from demo
    where id_konsul = 4
    group by id_konsul, staflow
) b on a.staflow = b.staflow
    and a.id_konsul = b.id_konsul 
    and a.created_at = b.created_at;
```

Or using a left join

```
select a.*
from demo a
left join demo b on a.id_konsul = b.id_konsul
                and a.staflow = b.staflow 
                and a.created_at < b.created_at
where a.id_konsul = 4 
and b.id_konsul is null
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/104a95/3)

To write above queries using laravel's query builder you can use following references

[Laravel Eloquent select all rows with max created_at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959102/laravel-eloquent-select-all-rows-with-max-created-at/47959128#47959128)

[Laravel - Get the last entry of each UID type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217420/laravel-get-the-last-entry-of-each-uid-type/49217481#49217481)

[Laravel Eloquent group by most recent record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830138/laravel-eloquent-group-by-most-recent-record/47830291#47830291)

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
SELECT * FROM test1 n 
WHERE created_at=(SELECT MAX(created_at)FROM test1 
  WHERE staflow=n.staflow) 
order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user INNER JOIN.

**Example:**

```
SELECT t0.* from {TABLE_NAME} AS t0 INNER JOIN {TABLE_NAME} t1 ON t0.staflow = t1.staflow WHERE t0.created_at > t1.created_at and t0.id_konsul = 4
```

Comment: i want to get all of staflow but newest form created_at

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id_konsul = 4 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1;
```