# Laravel distinct on join one to many

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group

I've found a couple of questions online similar to mine, but I can't seem to find a working answer.

I have 2 tables

**USER**

```
ID | FIRSTNAME  | EMAIL_ADDRESS
1  | Joe Bloggs | Joe@bloggs.com
```

**STATUS**

```
ID | USER_ID | STATUS | DATE
1  |  1      | 'In'   | 2018-06-04 09:01:00
2  |  1      | 'Out'  | 2018-06-04 09:00:00
```

I need to be able to Join the 2 tables together but only get the most recent status column by `date`, like this

```
ID | FIRSTNAME  | EMAIL_ADDRESS    | STATUS_ID | STATUS | DATE
1  | Joe Bloggs | Joe@bloggs.com   | 1         | 'In'   | 2018-06-04 09:01:00
```

I need to be able to run extra query builder arguments like `where`, because the user has the ability to pass in filters and search parameters if they require, so to be able to use the status table columns in my query builder, i'm doing a join like this

```
$users = Users::join('status', 'status.user_id', '=', 'user.id')->distinct('user.id');
```

Which then allows me to pass in any search parameters if I need them

```
         if(!empty($request->search)){
             $param = $request->search;
             $users = $users->where(function($query) use ($param){
                 $query->where('users.firstname', 'like', '%'.$param.'%')
                       ->orWhere('users.email_address', 'like', '%'.$param.'%');
             });
         }
         if(!empty($request->dateFrom)){
             if(!empty($request->dateTo)){
                 $users = $users->whereRaw('DATE(status.date) BETWEEN ? AND ?', [$request->dateFrom, $request->dateTo]);
             } else {
                 $users = $users->whereRaw('DATE(status.date) BETWEEN ? AND DATE(NOW())', [$request->dateFrom]);
             }
         }
```

Then run my `get()` at the end

```
    if($method == 'paginate'){
        $users = $users->paginate(10);
    } else {
        $users = $users->get();
    }
```

This returns the following

```
ID | FIRSTNAME  | EMAIL_ADDRESS    | STATUS_ID | STATUS | DATE
1  | Joe Bloggs | Joe@bloggs.com   | 1         | 'In'   | 2018-06-04 09:01:00
2  | Joe Bloggs | Joe@bloggs.com   | 1         | 'Out'  | 2018-06-04 09:00:00
```

I need to be able to use the foreign table columns as arguments in my `Where` functions, but I need to only return 1 row per user. How do I run a join, but only return 1 row for each of my users?

Comment: i assume `Joe Bloggs` has id `1` only. then u can do, `$users->unique('id')`;

Comment: sr did you check my answer?it works you dont have to ask 10 questions

Comment: It didnt work for me in my case @Eminem, i'm not sure what the problem could be. The task ended up changing so I no longer need to achieve this but thank you for your help.

Comment: it's not a matter of doing your task,for us too it takes effort and time to answer a question, you have asked multiple questions without awarding anyone,very rude

Comment: @Eminem you're right I apologise. Thank you for taking the effort to try and help me.

Answer (score 1):

To get latest record for each user you can use a self join for status table

```
select u.*,s.*
from user u
join status s on u.id  = s.user_id
left join status s1 on s.user_id = s1.user_id 
and s.date < s1.date 
where s1.user_id is null
```

Using query builder you might rewrite it as

```
DB::table('user as u')
  ->select('u.*', 's.*')
  ->join('status as s', 'u.id ', '=', 's.user_id')
  ->leftJoin('status as s1', function ($join) {
        $join->on('s.user_id', '=', 's1.user_id')
             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('s.date < s1.date'));
   })
  ->whereNull('s1.user_id')
  ->get();
```

[Laravel Eloquent select all rows with max created_at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959102/laravel-eloquent-select-all-rows-with-max-created-at/47959128#47959128)

[Laravel - Get the last entry of each UID type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217420/laravel-get-the-last-entry-of-each-uid-type/49217481#49217481)

[Laravel Eloquent group by most recent record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830138/laravel-eloquent-group-by-most-recent-record/47830291#47830291)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Laravel lets make the solution a bit more understandable and easier:
First Lets create the models for each table:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
       'FIRSTNAME', 
       'EMAIL_ADDRESS'
    ];

    public function status(){
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Status::class);
}
}
```

Now lets create the Status Model:

```
class Status extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $casts = [
        'USER_ID' => 'int',
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'USER_ID',
       'STATUS',
        'DATE'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class);
    }
}
```

Now you can use Eloquents like this:

```
 $result=User::whereHas('Status', function($q){
    $q->where('date', $current_date);
})->distinct('id')->get();
```

Hope it Helps!