# Laravel get latest record for each group

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to migrate some Raw SQL to an Eloquent (or Query Builder) scope on my model. My Parts history table looks like this:

```
+----+---------+--------+------------+
| id | part_id | status | created_at |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 | ...        |
|  2 |       1 |      2 | ...        |
|  3 |       2 |      1 | ...        |
|  4 |       1 |      2 | ...        |
|  5 |       2 |      2 | ...        |
|  6 |       1 |      3 | ...        |
```

Notice the same part_id can have multiple entries where the status is the same.

At the moment I use the following to select the latest status:

```
$part = Part::leftjoin( DB::raw("
 (SELECT t1.part_id, ph.status, t1.part_status_at 
  FROM (
    SELECT part_id, max(created_at) part_status_at
    FROM part_histories
    GROUP BY part_id) t1 
  JOIN part_histories ph ON ph.part_id = t1.part_id AND t1.part_status_at = ph.created_at) as t2
  )", 't2.part_id', '=', 'parts.id')->where( ... )
```

I am trying to make a scope on the parts model out of this, so far I have this:

```
public function scopeWithLatestStatus($query)
{
    return $query->join(DB::raw('part_histories ph'), function ($join) {
         $join->on('ph.part_id', '=', 't1.id')->on('t1.part_status_at', '=', 'ph.created_at');
      })
      ->from(DB::raw('(select part_id as id, max(created_at) part_status_at from part_histories GROUP BY part_id) t1'))
      ->select('t1.id', 'ph.part_status', 't1.part_status_at');
}
```

which is part way there (but still using some raw SQL), I just can't figure out the rest

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why?  If the raw SQL works fine then what benefits do you get from switching to an ORM?  I know that has nothing to do with the question really, I'm just curious.

Comment: Good point, Gordon :-) 
Mostly because I was changing other stuff to ORM. As it turns out I have decided to stick with the raw SQL as I didn't really explain my question very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could rewrite your query as left join to get the same results

```
select a.* 
from part_histories a
left join part_histories b on a.part_id = b.part_id 
                            and a.created_at < b.created_at
where b.part_id is null
```

and I guess you can transform easily above query in your scope something like

```
public function scopeWithLatestStatus($query)
{
    return $query->leftJoin('part_histories as b', function ($join) {
                $join->on('a.part_id', '=', 'b.part_id')
                     ->where('a.created_at', '<', 'b.created_at');
            })
        ->whereNull('b.part_id')
        ->from('part_histories as a')
        ->select('a.*');
}
```

[Laravel Eloquent select all rows with max created_at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959102/laravel-eloquent-select-all-rows-with-max-created-at/47959128#47959128)

[Laravel - Get the last entry of each UID type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217420/laravel-get-the-last-entry-of-each-uid-type/49217481#49217481)

[Laravel Eloquent group by most recent record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830138/laravel-eloquent-group-by-most-recent-record/47830291#47830291)

Edit using above query as `has` relation,To get the latest history for each part you can define a `hasOne` relation like

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class Part extends Model
{
    public function latest_history()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\PartHistory::class, 'part_id')
            ->leftJoin('part_histories as p1', function ($join) {
                $join->on('part_histories.part_id', '=', 'p1.part_id')
                    ->whereRaw(DB::raw('part_histories.created_at < p1.created_at'));
            })->whereNull('p1.part_id')
            ->select('part_histories.*');
    }
}
```

And then to load parts with their latest history you could eager load above defined mapping as

```
$parts = Part::with('latest_history')->get();
```

You will have a list of parts along with latest history as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => P1
            [latest_history] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [created_at] => 2018-06-16 08:25:10
                    [status] =>  1
                    [part_id] => 1
                )

        )
....
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my fault because I didn't make my issue clear enough - what you have provided works well - but I already had that bit working, albeit using a different methodology. 
What I should have asked was how to change the scope method to append the latest status to any ORM part query as: Part::withLatestStatus()->get()

Comment: @rareclass you want to load this data from  with your Part model ? Instead of applying scope

Comment: I want to apply scope rather than use an attribute, to avoid the n+1 problem when retrieving collections of parts.

Comment: @rareclass i guess if you could define this query as `hasOne` and do the eager loading then there wouldn't be a chance of n+1. Let me know if that makes sense then i will update my answer

Comment: you mean change it from the current `hasMany` relationship?

Comment: @rareclass i have updated my answer , Define a new hasOne on part model to load required related data

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't even aware you could do that with haseOne relationship

Comment: Now that I know a hasOne relationship can be used, I experimented and a simplified `return $this->hasOne(PartHistory::class, 'part_id')->latest();` _seems_ to give the correct results - does it, or only in some circumstances?

Comment: @rareclass Do you really think is there a need of `->latest()` on `hasOne()` ? `hasOne` will return only one record for parent/linked model so it me use of `latest()` doesn't make much sense here

Comment: OK, but I meant can I replace the whole of the `latest_history` method you have above (leftJoin etc), with just a simple hasOne relationship as it appears to give the same result?

Comment: @rareclass not sure for this i haven't tested , but if it gives you correct result set yes you can replace all the stuff