# Get latest item in OneTomany relationship laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship, one-to-many

:)

I've a problem with a relationship in my project, this is the situation, I have two models "Sucursales" and "Checklist", this is the logic... one sucursal can have many checklist, but is one request I only need to get the most recent sucursal's checklist... the simple relation works fine when I call it, but when I'm trying to get the most recent checklist the result is empty, here is the code:

Sucursales Model

```
class Sucursales extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'db_sucursales';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_sucursal';
    protected $fillable =['tipo_sucursal', 'no_sucursal', 'id_gcb', 'id_coordinacion', 'nombre_sucursal', 'id_estado', 'direccion_sucursal', 'telefono_sucursal', 'id_estatus'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function checkslist(){
        return $this->hasMany(ChecklistSucursal::class, 'id_sucursal','id_sucursal');
    }
}
```

Checklist model:

```
class ChecklistSucursal extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'db_checklist_sucursales';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_checklist';
    protected $fillable = [
        'folio', 'id_sucursal', 'id_usuario', 'nombre_aplicador', 'encargado_sucursal', 'puesto_encargado_sucursal', 'fecha_aplicacion', 'checklist','estatus','comentarios'
    ];

    public function sucursal(){
        return $this->hasOne(Sucursales::class, 'id_sucursal', 'id_sucursal');
    }
    
}
```

When I call:

```
$sucursales = Sucursales::with('checkslist')->orderBy('no_sucursal', 'asc')->get();
```

works fine, but when I call the next code:

```
$sucursales = Sucursales::with(['checkslist' => function($query){
                return $query->latest('fecha_aplicacion');
            }])
                            ->orderBy('no_sucursal', 'asc')
                            ->get();
```

the result is empty...

Please someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, this project is in laravel 5.5

Comment: Have a look at [Laravel get latest record for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831311/laravel-get-latest-record-for-each-group/50831563#50831563)

Comment: Thanks @MKhalidJunaid, I solved my issue 