# Laravel Inner join the last value of the right table

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get the last value of the login log of my user but I can't do it with this code:

```php
DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('login_logs', 'login_logs.id', '=', function($query) {
        $query->select('login_logs.id')
            ->where('users.id', '=','login_logs.user_id')
            ->orderBy('login_logs.created_at')
            ->limit(1);
    })->get();
```

I got 2 tables users and login log I want to get all users with the last login log can someone give me a hand? I am new in Laravel.

Edit:
i got this code for the sql:

```php
SELECT c.*, o.* 
FROM users c 
INNER JOIN login_logs o ON o.id = (
SELECT id 
FROM login_logs 
WHERE login_logs.users_id = c.id 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1)
```

Edit2:
this code work for me

```php
DB::table('users')
->leftJoin('login_logs', 'login_logs.id', '=', (DB::RAW('(
SELECT id FROM login_logs 
WHERE login_logs.user_id = users.id 
ORDER BY login_logs.id DESC 
LIMIT 1)')))
->select('users.*','login_logs.created_at as lastLogin','login_logs.type')
->get()
```

some best ideas?:

Comment: Are you familiar with Eloquent models and relationships?

Comment: i am using datatables https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/ and this not work with models :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get latest record from login log table for each user  you can use following self joined query

```
select u.*, l.*
from users u
join login_logs l on u.id = l.user_id
left join login_logs l1 on l.user_id = l1.user_id
and l.created_at < l1.created_at
where l1.user_id is null
```

Using query builder you might rewrite it as

```
DB::table('users as u')
  ->select('u.*', 'l.*')
  ->join('login_logs as l', 'u.id', '=', 'l.user_id')
  ->leftJoin('login_logs as l1', function ($join) {
        $join->on('l.user_id', '=', 'l1.user_id')
             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('l.created_at < l1.created_at'));
   })
  ->whereNull('l1.user_id')
  ->get();
```

[Laravel Eloquent select all rows with max created_at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959102/laravel-eloquent-select-all-rows-with-max-created-at/47959128#47959128)

[Laravel - Get the last entry of each UID type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217420/laravel-get-the-last-entry-of-each-uid-type/49217481#49217481)

[Laravel Eloquent group by most recent record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830138/laravel-eloquent-group-by-most-recent-record/47830291#47830291)

Comment: thanks for the reply, this is my sql code working SELECT c.*, o.* FROM users c INNER JOIN login_logs o ON o.id = (SELECT id FROM login_logs WHERE login_logs.users_id = c.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) how i can use it in laravel?

Comment: @JarloyzJuarez why do you want to run that query instead of what i have addressed in my answer, Give it a try and let me if you still don't get the right data or in case of error

Comment: sorry about that, you code is not working, the code return all login log for each users

Comment: @JarloyzJuarez I doubt that , this can't be true , Also can you give us a favor and include sample data set for your tables and table definitions using http://sqlfiddle.com/ or any other online tool or may be you can add in your question, So that i can verify what you stated is correct or not

Comment: oh men sorry i see my fault, some of my data log got the same datetime and that was the reaseon why you query was not working i fixed id changing l.created_at < l1.created_at for l.id < l1.id

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DB::table('users')
            ->join('login_logs', 'login_logs.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->order_by('login_logs.id', 'desc')
            ->first();
```

Comment: it only return one i want return all users with the last login date

Comment: remove ->first()

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
Inner Query will provide your last login detail of each user and join it by Table(Id)
with LEFT JOIN. So it will answer only your required user's details.
You may add WHERE CONDITION at Last to get Specific Id(User) detail

```
SELECT U.ID,
    LOGS.CREATED_AT
FROM USERS AS U
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT ID,
                MAX(CREATED_AT) AS CREATED_AT
            FROM LOGIN_LOGS
            GROUP BY ID
        ) AS LOGS
    ON  LOGS.ID = U.ID
--WHERE U.ID='your_user_id'
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i got this code working SELECT c.*, o.* FROM users c INNER JOIN login_logs o ON o.id = (SELECT id FROM login_logs WHERE login_logs.users_id = c.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)

Comment: 'ORDER BY' will slow down your Query. Currently, maybe you are working in Test Data. But having lacs of data will decrease your performance by ratio 30:70.

Comment: thanks for the reply, what you think about this? SELECT c.*, o.* FROM users c INNER JOIN login_logs o ON o.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM login_logs WHERE login_logs.user_id = c.id GROUP BY login_logs.user_id);

Comment: currently you are going 3-Steps ▼ usres[id]→ login_logs[id] → login_logs[user_id].
I am giving you the shortcut to proceed fast. ▲ usres[u_id]→ login_logs[u_id].
Now you choose which seems better.