# Laravel get last row value form many table in one to Many relationship

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group

I am building an application which has a model with one to many relationship. In the model, the student table has one to many relationship with student address details. I want to retrieve the last row from address details table. I am stuck on how to retrieve that data. I could not work out from similar answer on this website.

My current solution is this

```php
$students = Student::with('visaDetails', 'addresses', 'instituteDetails', 'subAgents',
            'staffDetails', 'commissionDetails', 'comments')->paginate(16);

        foreach ($students as $student){
            foreach ($student->addresses as $address){
                dd($address->id);
            }
        }
```

My student model is as follow

```php
class Student extends Model
{
    //One to Many relation to student address

    public function addresses(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Address');
    }
}
```

But this solutions is not efficient as number of record grows exponentially.
Also, I need to find last row for other many table as well.

If anybody could help me then it would be very nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get latest record from address table for each student you can go with following self joined query

```
SELECT s.*, a.*
from students s
join address a on s.id = a.student_id
left join address a1 on a.student_id = a1.student_id
and a.created_at < a1.created_at
where a1.student_id is null
```

I assume by latest means you need address with most recent `created_at` attribute.

Using query builder you might rewrite it as

```
DB::table('students as s')
  ->select('s.*', 'a.*')
  ->join('address as a', 's.id', '=', 'a.student_id')
  ->leftJoin('address as a1', function ($join) {
        $join->on('a.student_id', '=', 'a1.student_id')
             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('a.created_at < a1.created_at'));
   })
  ->whereNull('a1.student_id')
  ->get();
```

[Laravel Eloquent select all rows with max created_at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959102/laravel-eloquent-select-all-rows-with-max-created-at/47959128#47959128)

[Laravel - Get the last entry of each UID type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217420/laravel-get-the-last-entry-of-each-uid-type/49217481#49217481)

[Laravel Eloquent group by most recent record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830138/laravel-eloquent-group-by-most-recent-record/47830291#47830291)

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfectly. What should i do when I need to populate  latest row from all the many tables. like address, institute, staff etc.

Comment: @Bikram for multiple tables the would become more complex and might be slow when data increases i guess you can fetch them by individual queries for each table, For multiple table in same query the logic is same as for address , each table will be self joined

Comment: I am using multiple join for now. The performance has not degraded till now. Let's see what happens when data increases.

Answer (score 0):

I created a package that allows you to limit the number of eager loading results per parent:
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Use the `HasEagerLimit` trait in both the parent and the related model.

```php
class Student extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}

class Address extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}
```

Then you can apply `->limit(1)` to your relationship:

```php
$students = Student::with([
    'addresses' => function($query) {
        $query->limit(1);
    },
    'visaDetails', 'instituteDetails', 'subAgents',
    'staffDetails', 'commissionDetails', 'comments'
])->paginate(16);
```