# Get latest data of a specific column using eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group

How do i get the last/latest data of each specific user_id.

**Submission table**

| id | user_id | status | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | redo | somedatetime | somedatetime => `dont want this` |
| 2 | 3 | redo | somedatetime | somedatetime |
| 3 | 4 | redo | somedatetime | somedatetime |
| 4 | 5 | redo | somedatetime | somedatetime |

ID 2 is not a redundancy. I'm keeping track of the records. I need to grab id 2,3,4. I've tried using

```
Submission::where('status','redo')->distinct('user_id')->get();
```

but it returns all the value

**UPDATE**

For reference purpose here is the real structure of the table

[image: Submission table]

as you can see user_id 78 has 2 redos which is 89 and 90. Im trying to get the latest/last one which is 90.

Comment: try something like this `Submission::where('status','redo')->latest()->groupBy('user_id')->get();`

Comment: @Joseph Im getting ID 1 instead of 2

Comment: could you add the result please

Comment: @Joseph try checking my update. thanks

Comment: are you want to get the latest record for a given user or the last record for all of the users?

Comment: all the users @Joseph

Comment: give me a while to try it

Comment: could you try this answer it may helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent select all rows with max created\_at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959102/laravel-eloquent-select-all-rows-with-max-created-at) or [Laravel get last row value form many table in one to Many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883935/laravel-get-last-row-value-form-many-table-in-one-to-many-relationship/50884160#50884160)

Answer (score 2):

you can get the last ids then get the complete records:

```
 $max_ids = Submission::query()
       ->where('status','redo')

        ->select('user_id', DB::raw('max(id) max_ids'))
        ->groupBy('user_id')->pluck('max_ids');

    $lasts = Submission::whereIn('id', $max_ids)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this with a sub query:

```
Submission::from(Submission::orderBy('id', 'desc'), 't')
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->get();
```

Probably will have to make adjustments, not tested, but the idea is a sub query would get the ordering then the main query would do the grouping.

Comment: could you explain what is the `t` letter in the second attribute of `from` method? i like this answer you are a genus