# Laravel Limit within Join

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following in one of my controllers:

```
$documentReminders = DB::table('employees')
                ->where('department_id',5)
                ->join('employee_attachments', 'employees.id', '=', 'employee_attachments.employeeID')
                    ->whereIn('category', ['Medical Examiners Certificate','Drivers License'] )
                ->orderBy('employee_attachments.endDate')
                ->get();
```

This does successfully return all of the records I was expecting it too, but the problem here is there are too many (I'll explain).

For each employee record, there could be a few dozen of each of the `employee_attachments.category` (say one employee could have 8 of both, while one could have 15).

What I would like is to be able to limit the number of `employee_attachments` returned for each employee to one (1) of each category and that being the most recent record within that category in reference to its `employee_attachments.endDate` field.

So basically if I had the following `employee_attachments` table

```
employeeID     || category                      || endDate
1              || Drivers License               || 2019-01-01
1              || Drivers License               || 2017-01-01
2              || Drivers License               || 2016-01-01
1              || Drivers License               || 2018-01-01
1              || Medical Examiners Certificate || 2017-01-01
1              || Medical Examiners Certificate || 2018-01-01
1              || Medical Examiners Certificate || 2019-01-01
2              || Medical Examiners Certificate || 2017-01-01
2              || Medical Examiners Certificate || 2020-01-01
```

Then I would want the following returned:

```
employeeID     || category                      || endDate
1              || Drivers License               || 2019-01-01
1              || Medical Examiners Certificate || 2019-01-01
2              || Drivers License               || 2016-01-01
2              || Medical Examiners Certificate || 2020-01-01
```

Comment: You write "limit the number of employee_attachments returned for each employee to one (1)", but in your sample data you limit the number of `employee_attachments` to one per *employee and category*.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir - Sorry typo, the sample data is correct, and I will fix the question here in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way.

```
 $documentReminders = DB::table('employees')
        ->join('employee_attachments', 'employees.id', '=', 'employee_attachments.employeeID')
        ->select(['employee_attachments.employeeID','employee_attachments.category',DB::raw('MAX(employee_attachments.endDate) as eDate')])
            ->where('department_id',5)
    ->whereIn('category', ['Medical Examiners Certificate','Drivers License'] )
    ->groupBy('employee_attachments.employeeID','employee_attachments.category')
    ->orderBy('eDate','DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: At this time I get a Syntax error: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column `truckin.employee_attachments.endDate` which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode = only_full_group_by -

Comment: remove the `->orderBy('employee_attachments.endDate','DESC')` clause and try again, it should work,

Comment: I'll give you that, it does work but another issue crops up in that I do require the orderBy, as it is technically a list of upcoming expirations, it needs to show the soonest to latest of the coming attachments in the returned array.

Comment: @Matthew i edit the answer above and added an allias for date and modified the `orderBy` , check that and let me know

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest record for each employee from `employee_attachments` , you could introduce a self join with `employee_attachments` table with additional join criteria where `endDate` should be highest

```
$documentReminders = DB::table('employees as e')
                        ->where('department_id',5)
                        ->join('employee_attachments as ea', 'e.id', '=', 'ea.employeeID')
                        ->leftJoin('employee_attachments as ea1', function ($join) {
                            $join->on('ea.employeeID', '=', 'ea1.employeeID')
                                 ->where('ea.category', '=', 'ea1.category')
                                 ->where('ea.endDate', '<', 'ea1.endDate');
                        })
                        ->whereNull('ea1.employeeID')
                        ->whereIn('ea.category', ['Medical Examiners Certificate','Drivers License'] )
                        ->orderBy('ea.endDate')
                        ->select('e.*','ea.*')
                        ->get();
```

[Laravel Eloquent select all rows with max created_at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959102/laravel-eloquent-select-all-rows-with-max-created-at/47959128#47959128)

[Laravel - Get the last entry of each UID type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217420/laravel-get-the-last-entry-of-each-uid-type/49217481#49217481)

[Laravel Eloquent group by most recent record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830138/laravel-eloquent-group-by-most-recent-record/47830291#47830291)

In raw sql it would be

```
select ea.*
from employee_attachments ea
left join employee_attachments ea1 
     on ea.employeeID = ea1.employeeID
     and ea.category = ea1.category
     and ea.endDate < ea1.endDate
where ea1.employeeID is null
order by ea.employeeID
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8dc7c0/2)

Comment: At this moment, I get the following error returned, though I did see your example and know that it should be close: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'truckin.employee_attachments ea' doesn't exist (SQL: select `e`.*, `ea`.* from `employees` as `e` inner join `employee_attachments ea` on `e`.`id` = `ea`.`employeeID` left join `employee_attachments` as `ea1` on `ea`.`employeeID` = `ea1`.`employeeID` and `ea`.`category` = ea1.category and `ea`.`endDate` < ea1.endDate where `department_id` = 5 and `ea1`.`employeeID` is null and `ea`.`category` in (Medical Examiners Ce...

Comment: @Matthew It might be due to missing `AS` keyword in `join(...)` part check updated answer

Comment: Alright, now it is coming through just fine but it still returns multiple copies of the same category record for an employee. I have a meeting to go to in a few so I will work on this later, I just figured mention that. Thank you for your help though too!

Comment: @Matthew , check my answer bellow and let me know your feedback

Comment: @Matthew It there a chance that there can be morethan 1 rows for single employee and same category with same highest date in employee_attachments table?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid - No, all of the records that were returned all have different endDates.

Comment: @Matthew can you add your sample data set here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8dc7c0/2 and reproduce same issue