# Limiting the result of nested relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, nested, relationship

I have a nested relationship that I want to set a condition and a limit.

```php
$data = Accommodation::with('accommodationFacilities', 'city')
    ->take(10)
    ->with('accommodationRooms.roomPricingHistory')
    ->limit(2)
    ->where('is_deleted', 0)
    ->paginate(10);
```

Now I have a nested relation on line 2 that I want to limit this relation by: `roomPricingHistory`.

The code limits the parent relation which is: `accommodationRooms`.

Any idea how I can limit the child relation and how can I set an if for it so if a column is === 0 this row should be loaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel eager loading with limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607088/laravel-eager-loading-with-limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try constraining the eager loading

```php
$data = Accommodation::with('accommodationFacilities', 'city')
    ->take(10)
    ->with(['accommodationRooms.roomPricingHistory' => function($query){
        $query->limit(2)
    }])
    ->limit(2)
    ->where('is_deleted', 0)
    ->paginate(10);
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: when i use 2 nothing loads but when i increase number to 12 for example 3 units appear any way i think i must look more for it