# Get first image for each product

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I try to get latest *10* products with its images but only the first image
so that is what i try

```
$newProducts = \App\Product::latest()->with(['images', function($el){

   $el->first();

}])->with('category')->take(10)->get();
```

but it gives me this error

```
mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

it has a `morph` relation between `product` and `image`

**Product Model**

```
class Product extends Model {
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Image::class, 'imageable');
    }
}
```

**Image Model**

```
class Image extends Model {
    public function imageable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above solutions are all good. I personally prefer a different solution that I think is gonna be ideal.

I am gonna define a different relationship for a product:

```
class Product extends Model {
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Image::class, 'imageable');
    }

    public function firstImage()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Image::class, 'imageable');
    }
}
```

So you can access the first image directly or eager load the relationship:

```
$product->firstImage;

$product->load('firstImage');

Product::with('firstImage');
```

Just FYI, I learnt about this and other useful database tricks from Jonathan Reinink in [Laracon Online 2018](https://laracon.net/2018).

Comment: I like it it more optimized and clean without any external package

Answer (score 2):

When using with as a key value array, the `$el` parameter to the closure will be a query builder that has not executed yet.

The way to limit query builders of results is to use `take()`. Therefor your code should look like this.

```
->with(['images', function($el) {
    $el->take(1);
}])
```

**Edit** To make this solution work, you will need an extra [package](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit). Using the following trait should make it work and using limit instead. See the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607088/laravel-5-eager-loading-with-limit).

```
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;

->with(['images', function($el) {
    $el->limit(1);
}])
```

**Alternatively Laravel solution** is to use transformation like properties, where you can create your own custom properties, in the function naming starting with get and ending with attribute.

```
class Product {
    protected $appends = ['first_image'];

    public function getFirstImageAttribute() {
        return $this->images->first();
    }
}
```

Now if you use standard `Laravel` serialization all products will have an first_image field and in your code you can access it like so.

```
$product->first_image;
```

To avoid performance hits, include images using `with('images')`.

Comment: the `mutations` way works fine thanks, but as you said To avoid performance hits, include images using `with('images')` i try it but it get the same error

Comment: here it is what it try `$newProducts = \App\Product::latest()->with(['images', function($el){
            $el->take(1);
        }])->get();`

Comment: You can't use `take()` inside of a `with` constraint. The way eager loading works is it loads all the parent records, then loads all the children with a `where parent_id in ([previously loaded parent ids])`. When you do `take()` it essentially tells it to load a single child TOTAL, regardless of how many parents there are

Comment: @jfadich could you tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: Using @mrhn's "Alternatively Laravel solution" should work. The one caveat is if you use `protected $appends = ['first_image'];` you should also use `protected $with = ['images']`

Comment: Oh i actually thaught the first solution would work, i guess using https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit should be the other option

Comment: but which one would be optimized [best solution] for this problem ?

Comment: I made an edit to an package that seems to solve the problem. In general i would not be that afraid of performance unless you are dealing with high load systems.

Comment: @mrhn you awesome thanks a lot sir it works perfectly

Comment: @mrhn your answer in awesome sir but it need for an external package and i try to save resources as i could

Answer (score 0):

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}

public function firstImage()
{
    return $this->images()->first();
}
```

Simply create a function that defines relationship between product and its images.
Then create a function that gets the first image