# Condition only on latest record in hasMany relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two table `users` and `users_logs` .

The `users_logs` table is linked with `users` by `user_id`.

The `users_logs` table may have multiple entries against different users, like 100 records may have against one `user_id`.

I want to fetch all users from `users` table with only one latest record of each users in `users_logs` table, then want to check a condition on the latest records of each user.

i have also created a hasMany relation in `users` table.

```
public function users_logs_details(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\UsersLog', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

The code i tried is

```
$users = User::with(['users_logs_details'])
            ->whereHas('users_logs_details', function($query) {
                return $query->where('status', '=', 1)->latest()->take(1);
            })->get();
```

But i am not getting desired result because, this query is checking all records in `users_logs` table, but i want to check only the latest record.If status=1 is valid for any record of a user in `users_logs` table then it is returning the record, but i want to check status=1 only in the latest record, if status=0 in latest record (irrespective whether it is 1 in old record) it should return no result for that record.
Please help, i would be highly thankful.

Note : images are for references only

[image]

[image]

Comment: Share your table data

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Rwd : Laravel 5.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607088/laravel-5-eager-loading-with-limit - Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

A sub query join can be your solution. Sub query join will select only the latest event log, join it with the users and filter it by the status you need. To avoid making user field ambiguous, select only the user fields.

```
User::leftJoinSub(
    UsersLog::whereColumn('users_logs.user_id', 'users.id')
        ->latest()
        ->limit(1),
    'users_logs',
    'users_logs.user_id',
    'users.id'
)->where('users_logs.status', 1)
->select('users.*')
->get();
```

Comment: Code is untested and probably wont work first try, but try it and let's take it from there